# Removing Duplicate String from array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm really struggling with this part of my problem. I've been watching videos for hours and researching online but I can't seem to get it correct. I need to produce a for loop that checks the string for meg , removes it and shift the remaining elements. this is not an arraylist.

> Write a second, traditional for loop that checks each 
>   element for the String “
>   Meg
>   ”, if found in the 
>   array, remove it, shift the remaining elements, and display the array of names.

I know my for loop would go between my last customer name & the for to print it.I'm just confused on what to do next.

Here is my current code:

```
public class CustomerListerArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String customerName[] = new String[7];
        customerName[0] = "Chris";
        customerName[1] = "Lois";
        customerName[2] = "Meg";
        customerName[3] = "Peter";
        customerName[4] = "Stewie";
        for (int i = customerName.length - 1; i > 3; i--) {
            customerName[i] = customerName[i - 2];
        }
        customerName[3] = "Meg";
        customerName[4] = "Brian";
        for (String name: customerName) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow the instructions you have been given, you could try something like:

```
int max = customerName.length;
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {   // Traditional for loop
    if ("Meg".equals(customerName[i]) {    // Look for the name "Meg"
        // If found, shift the array elements down one.
        for (int j = i; j < (max - 1); j++) {
            customerName[j] = customerName[j+1];
        }
        i--;  // Check the i'th element again in case we just move "Meg" there.
        max--; // Reduce the size of our search of the array.
    }
}
```

Once this is done, you can iterate through the result and print the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    System.out.println(customerName[i]);
}
```

Comment: @sam2090 there's nothing in the question about a case-insensitive search, but this could certainly be done if required.

Comment: @dave Thank you so much for your help. This removes the first Meg but not the second for some odd reason.

Comment: @BlueJay looks like there's a bug then :)   I'd say it was broken if "Meg" occurred in consecutive elements. I think I've fixed it.

Comment: @3kings I think I need both. The first to handle consecutive instances of the word we're searching for. The second is to stop us searching elements that are now empty because we shifted them.

Comment: you are amazing @dave

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to loop over all the indexes of your array and check if they equal `"Meg"`. If it is not the case, the value of the index is concatenated to the `StringBuilder` object.

At the end, we take our `StringBuilder` object string's value and split it with the additional spaces we put between the names.

And we finally have our new `String` array with the wanted size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String customerName[] = new String[7];
    customerName[0] = "Chris";
    customerName[1] = "Lois";
    customerName[2] = "Meg";
    customerName[3] = "Peter";
    customerName[4] = "Stewie";
    customerName[5] = "Meg";
    customerName[6] = "Brian";
    StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
    for (String name: customerName) {
        if (!name.equals("Meg")) names.append(name + " ");
    }
    String[] myNewArray = names.toString().split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myNewArray));
}
```

Output :

```
[Chris, Lois, Peter, Stewie, Brian]
```

Comment: @sam2090 No => "each element for the String “ Meg ”"